# How can we sum the following convergent series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{n-3}} \frac{(n)(\cot(\frac{\pi}{n}))}{4}$$

Is there a way to evaluate this sum by hand? I know it converges as the function being summed approaches zero very quickly. Desmos shows the sum converging to 0.852, but I'm not sure how to find it by hand. It's a step of a math problem that I am working on for my own enjoyment. I'd really appreciate your help in showing this sum by hand. I haven't learned how to do this yet in school, but I'm curious about it and willing to research the methods used. Thanks.

Comment: The decrease of the terms is not really fast and the evaluation of the cotangents by hand is a little painful. What accuracy do you need ?

Comment: Hello.  I'm actually making a video about this problem. I'm looking for good accuracy, but what I'm really looking for is how I can learn to evaluate this myself. I was just curious about the method of solving this, both proving convergence of the sum and finding the value that it converges to. I was hoping to share this method in a video. For context, it's the sum of the areas of polygons with side lengths shrinking by a factor of 1/2 as you add additional sides (triangle with side 1, square with side length 1/2, pentagon with side length 1/4, etc.).

Comment: We could do much better adding more terms in the expansion. The problem is that this would involve polylogarithm function which you may not know. Adding one term would give $0.852230196656$, adding the next would give $0.852229887410$ while the "exact" summation would be $0.852229881303$

Comment: Fully by hand would take like a day of work, I guess. "Good accuracy" is no answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since we kow the exact value of the cotangent function for $\frac \pi 3$,$\frac \pi 4$,$\frac \pi 5$ and $\frac \pi 6$,we can write $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{n-3}} \frac{n\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}{4}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{35 \sqrt{3}}{128}+\frac{5}{64} \sqrt{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}+\sum_{n=7}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{n-3}} \frac{n\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}{4}$$

Now, for large values of $n$, we have
$$n\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)=\frac{n^2}{\pi }-\frac{\pi }{3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which makes
$$\sum_{n=7}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{n-3}} \frac{n\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}{4}\sim \frac{61}{864 \pi }-\frac{\pi }{2304}$$ which would give, as an *approximate* value

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{n-3}} \frac{n\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}{4}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{35 \sqrt{3}}{128}+\frac{5}{64} \sqrt{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}+\frac{61}{864 \pi }-\frac{\pi }{2304}\approx 0.852247$$ while the "exact" value  would be $0.852230$. This is not too bad.

Comment: +1 Good idea to start the remaining sum from a larger  $n$, here $n=7$, to improve the approximation of the $\cot$

Answer (score 2):

This a comment too long to be placed in the comment box.

We can derive a better converging series for

$$s= \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{n}{4^{n-2}} \cot(\frac{\pi}{n})\tag{1a}$$
$$s_{N}\simeq 0.8522298813029800625557412291916997005619\\5391003233107805879735766771134412975895\\46394147773051709659...\tag{1b}$$

by substituting $\cot$ by this formula (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html, formula (57))

$$\cot(z) = \frac{1}{z}-\frac{2}{\pi } \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{z}{\pi }\right)^{2 k-1} \zeta (2 k)\tag{2}$$

and doing the n-sum which gives

$$s_{1}=\frac{104}{27 \pi }-\frac{8}{\pi } \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(4 \operatorname{Li}_{2 k-2}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-4^{-k}-1\right) \zeta (2 k)\tag{3}$$

Here $\operatorname{Li}$ is the polylog function and $\zeta$ is Riemann's zeta function.

Notice that the bracket under the k-sum in $(3)$ must be kept together for the sum to converge.

Comparing the partial sums divided by the numerical value $s_{N}$ of $s$

$$(s /s_{N})_{k=1}^{k=5} = \{0.801442,0.927617,0.97525,0.991907,0.997439\}$$

$$(s_{1} /s_{N})_{k=1}^{k=5} = \{1.02908,1.00286,1.0003,1.00003,1.\}$$

we see the better convergence.

Taking just the first partial sum of the series $s$ we are off from final value by almost 20%, whereas for the series $s_{1}$ the error is only 3%.

Admittedly, this new series is not particularly well suited to be done "by hand".

But with these tables of numerical values (and some patience) you could nevertheless do it

$$\left(4 \operatorname{Li}_{2 k-2}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)_{k=1}^{k=5}=\{1.33333,1.07061,1.01646,1.004,1.00099\}$$

$$\left(\zeta (2 k)\right)_{k = 1}^{k=5} = \{1.64493,1.08232,1.01734,1.00408,1.00099\}$$

**Discussion**

The speed of convergence of the two series differs appreciably.

To get 100 exact digits the original series $s$ needs 180 terms (0.5555 digits per term), whereas the series $s_{1}$ needs only 110 terms (0.9091 digits per term).

I'd like to acknowledge help from @Roman for the exact calculation of the sum to high precision. The solution https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208973/16361 uses Sum rather than NSum.